# With 'ConstructorInfo' from a constructed generic type, how to I get the matching 'ConstructorInfo' from the open type?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, reflection

In .NET, I have an instance of `ConstructorInfo`. The declaring type is a constructed generic type (aka `foo.DeclaringType.IsConstructedGenericType == true`). I want to retrieve the `ConstructorInfo` instance that belongs to the open type - that is, the generic type definition of the declaring type.

It's straightforward to obtain the open type itself with `foo.DeclaringType.GetGenericTypeDefinition()`; however, at this point, there is no obvious way to get the matching constructor. I can re-enumerate all constructors on both sides, but then, I am still facing the problem of matching those two lists together; and I am not sure that .NET provides any guarantees that the constructors will be enumerated in the same order.

Does anyone has a way to obtain the original `ConstructorInfo` counterpart?

Answer (score 3):

I think you can match the constructors using the `MetadataToken` property:

```
 var closed = foo.GetType().GetConstructors().Select(c => c.MetadataToken);
 var open = foo.GetType().GetGenericTypeDefinition().GetConstructors().Select(o => o.MetadataToken);
 var b = Enumerable.SequenceEqual(closed, open); //returns true
```

It seems that the closed and open version of the constructors have the same metadata token, so this would be a way to hook up both lists. This holds up even if the generic class and the closed type are defined in different assemblies.

I haven't found anything that certifies this as documented behavior but you should be able to investigate further in the [ECMA C# and Common Language Infrastructure Standards](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=99212) or the [Standard ECMA-335 - Common Language Infrastructure (CLI)](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=65552)

Comment: Now if only I could figure out how to do it for .Net Standard 1.1 (no `MetadataToken` property!) I'd be a happy boy.  +1 btw